# Linux: location in memory of initramfs

Tags: linux-kernel, initramfs, x86

What is the standard location in the RAM of the initramfs (0xSOMETHING) ? If it is not specific, how do I specify an address to load initramfs from during boot?

Is it possible to run make menuconfig and edit the location of the initramfs? (I am making my own bootloader in NASM. Right now, it supports Loading a bzImage and kernel command line (`root=/dev/sda1 foo=bar`). So there is no problem of breaking the boot process. Also, the architecture is 64 bit x86, and the version is 4.7.2.

Comment: It's different depending on the kernel version, the kernel config, the system architecture, and sometimes also the bootloader being used.

Comment: @Hydranix: Is it possible to run make menuconfig and edit the location of the initramfs? (I am making my own bootloader in NASM. Right now, it supports Loading a bzImage and kernel command line ('root=/dev/sda1 foo=bar'). So there is no problem of breaking the boot process) Also, the architecture is 64 bit x86, and the version is 4.7.2

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's a pretty unusual requirement.

Answer (score 2):

It is the task of the bootloader to choose a memory address for the initramfs and load it from the file to the chosen address. This address is then passed to the kernel at boot time. Note that there is also an alternative way to pass the initramfs to the kernel: you can embed the initramfs cpio archive in the kernel image.